# Material button not displaying properly despite adding theme

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design, materialbutton

I am using material buttons in my angular project

```
   <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Buy</button>
   <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
```

and added theme in custom-theme.scss

```
   @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

but only normal HTML buttons got rendered, instead of mat button.

[image]

It's happening similarly for some other components as well (mat-form-field).
Any thoughts?

Comment: is your custom-theme.scss properly imported in the app and have you checked in the browser debugging tool if the css file is successfully loaded?

Comment: Yea, it is properly imported and loaded

Comment: As explained in the Material Documentation you should add the css file of the theme to your angular.json and import it in your styles.css. checkout this link https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: did you ever get a resolution to this?